# Django - how to delete objects in the database?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, object

So, I'm having problems deleting objects in django project's database. I have a model in my models.py file that looks like this.

```
class Myteam(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    QB = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    QBscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    RB1 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    RB1score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    RB2 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    RB2score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    WR = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    WR1score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    WR2 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    WR2score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    TE = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    TEscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    D = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    Dscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    K = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    Kscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I want to be able to delete information in this model. In my project, I have this model's information displayed in a table that looks like this [table/html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSNUU.jpg) My goal is to click the "drop" button and have that line of info deleted. I've been following some tutorials and advice on making a delete function for my views.py and I can't get it to work. It seems pretty simple but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Here's my views.py and urls.py

```
def delete_player(request, id):
    player = Myteam.objects.get(id=id)
    #print(player.id)
    player.delete()
    return redirect('index')
```

```
path('delete_player/<int:id>', views.delete_player, name="delete_player")
```

here's my html...

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
                                      
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black;">QB</td>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ team.QB }} <a href="{% url 'delete_player' 
 id=player.id %}"></a><button id="delete_button">Drop</button></a> </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black;"></th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ QBscore }}</th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black;"></th>
        </tr>    
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. A better approach is to make another view which deletes the object from the database.

In my opinion, you already have a form, now, in the drop button, give it an id same as your model object has. And through some frontend javascript, you can put some event listeners like onclick. When someone clicks on the button, that event listener function should run, and through ajax, send data to that view, in which the database object is deleted. In ajax, you should post id and csrf token...

I should put an example here, but I do not have it now.

Comment: What do you mean by make another view that deletes the object from the database? I thought the view I've already made should be doing that.

Comment: You have a form, and in the form tag, you have an attribute called action. Currently action="", so submitted form will send data to the same url. So make a new view (url, and view both), that will be accepting form data, and in html, in form tag, change action="url to new view"...

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to save the database after deleting the object.

player.save()